# ¿Cómo puedo crear una thumbnails en c#?

Tags: c#

Cómo puedo crear una thumbnails en c# de un **archivo cualquiera** para el explorador de windows?

Comment: No me queda claro aun, podrias explicarte mas a fondo

Comment: Si, bien, lo que quiero es crear una vista en miniatura de un archivo cualquiera (.loquesea) para que windows la reconosca, como por ejemplo.

Comment: Cuando no tienes lector de pdf, no tienes su vista en miniatura, pero cuando instalas uno este hace que windows le ponga una vista en miniatura, entiendes.

Comment: Ah ok y esto seria cuando instales tu app y tenga un tipo de archivo asociado

Comment: Por ahí va la cosa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias a todos por sus respuestas, pero después de tanto tiempo he encontrado [aquí](http://www.walkingtarget.com/?p=20) como hacer un Thumnail Provider usando IExtractImage, me funciona, pero cada vez que entro en la carpeta que contiene mis archivos .loquesea, windows empieza a cargar sus vistas en miniatura, y también sucede si doy F5. Por lo que ahora necesito que guarde en caché estas thumbns, en algo como un "**thumbcache.db**". Gracias

Ejemplo del código que utilicé:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Drawing;

namespace IExtractImage_Example
{
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("IExtractImage_Example.ExtractImage"), Guid("7CA3151C-2F5C-11E0-B2B8-B039E0D72085")]
public class ExtractImage : IExtractImage, IPersistFile
{
    #region ExtractImage Private Fields

    private Size m_size = Size.Empty;
    private string m_filename = String.Empty;

    #endregion

    private const long S_OK = 0x00000000L;
    private const long E_PENDING = 0x8000000AL;

    #region IExtractImage Members
    public long GetLocation(out StringBuilder pszPathBuffer, int cch, ref int pdwPriority, ref SIZE prgSize, int dwRecClrDepth, ref int pdwFlags)
    {
        pszPathBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        pszPathBuffer.Append(m_filename);
        m_size = new Size(prgSize.cx, prgSize.cy);

        if (((IEIFLAG)pdwFlags & IEIFLAG.ASYNC) != 0)
            return E_PENDING;

        return S_OK;
    }

    public long Extract(out IntPtr phBmpThumbnail)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(m_size.Width, m_size.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, m_size.Width, m_size.Height);
            }
        }
        phBmpThumbnail = bmp.GetHbitmap();

        return S_OK;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IPersistFile Members
    public void GetClassID(out Guid pClassID)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetCurFile(out string ppszFileName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int IsDirty()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Load(string pszFileName, int dwMode)
    {
        m_filename = pszFileName;
    }

    public void Save(string pszFileName, bool fRemember)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SaveCompleted(string pszFileName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que -generalmente- son los programas asociados a cierto tipo de archivos, por ejemplo al '.pdf', los que permiten obtener la miniatura pues traen consigo los "codecs" o instrucciones que permiten leer parte del archivo, por consiguiente, si quieres generar la miniatura con un programa en C# entonces este debería ser capaz de leer los datos de cualquier archivo para generar una miniatura acorde, ya sea un fotograma, un ícono, un texto, etc.

No necesariamente que lo lea completo pero si que acceda a cierta información contenida en el archivo, y aún así deberías poder asociar la extensión a tu programa para que Windows sepa que debe usarlo para generar la miniatura.

Comment: Pero yo quiero poner una vista en miniatura que puedo extraer del archivo, ejemplo de un archivo que esta comprimido

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un **Setup Project** o **Setup Wizard** para generar el proyecto de instalado de la aplicación. (El resultado sera el mismo, pero el wizard nos lleva de la mano)

En la Solución da clic "Add" (Agregar) -> "New Project ..." (Nuevo Proyecto)

Si usas el Wizard preguntara el tipo de aplicación, sera **Windows aplication** y lo que se incluirá, necesariamente debe ser  el **Primary output**.

Después de agregar el Proyecto de Setup da clic derecho sobre el nombre que hayamos elegido "View" (Vista) -> "File Types" (Tipos de archivo)

Agrega el tipo de archivo .loquesea, si hay algún archivo .ico se encontrara cuando veamos la propiedad "Icon" (Icono)

En Command selecionaremos el **Primary output** que pueda usar el archivo, por ejemplo `Primary output from WindowsFormsApplication1 (Active)` y en extension `.loquesea`

O podemos agregar un archivo .ico cualquiera, para esto vamos a la vista "File System" y en Application Folder agregamos nuestro archivo ico (podemos ponerlo en una subcarpeta si se desea) y ahora regresamos a la vista "File Types" y lo seleccionamos

Para generar nuestro instalador damos clic derecho sobre el proyecto setup y seleccionamos "Build" o "Rebuild" el cual generara dos archivos uno `.exe` y otro `.msi` con los cuales podemos instalar en otra pc, y cuando se encuentre un archivo `.loquesea` se mostrar nuestro icono seleccionado en lugar del icono por default de windows

Mas info en:

[How to: Create or Add a Setup Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Properties for the File Types Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c219k91z(v=vs.100).aspx)

**Nota**: Las versiones Express de Visual Studio no tienen incluido la opción de Proyectos de instalación

Si no tienes la opción en la edición Comunity de Visual Studio 2013 o 2015 puedes descargarlo desde aqui:

[Para 2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects)

[Para 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects)

---

Otra opción, es crear la asociación desde nustro código.

En channel 9 hicieron en algún momento un [proyecto para esto](https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Sandbox/249856-System-File-Association), donde podemos bajar el código fuent, construir la dll y agregarla a nuestro proyecto

Para agregar nuestra asociación usamos la clase `FileAssociationInfo`

```
FileAssociationInfo fai = new FileAssociationInfo(".loquesea");
if (!fai.Exists)
{
     fai.Create(progId, PerceivedTypes.Text , contentType, openwithList)
}
```

Comment: no tengo esa opcion en VS-2012 y no puedo descargar esa opcion

Comment: Esoty casi seguro que para la versión 2012 no se habilito esta opción, tendrias que actualizar a VS2013 o VS2015, si es posible. Agregare otra opción en un edit

Answer (score 0):

```
private const string Path_IMAGENES = "imagenes";
  private const int ANCHO_MAX = 100;
  private const int ALTO_MAX = 80;

  private bool ThumbnailCallback() {
    return false;
  }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     string rutaImg = Server.MapPath(Path_IMAGENES + @"/" + Request["src"]);
     if (!System.IO.File.Exists(rutaImg)) {
       Response.End();
    } else {
       System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(rutaImg);

       double factor = 0;
       int nuevoAlto = 0, nuevoAncho = 0;

       if (img.Height / ALTO_MAX >= img.Width / ANCHO_MAX) {
        factor = ALTO_MAX * 1.0 / img.Height;
       } else {
        factor = ANCHO_MAX * 1.0 / img.Width;
       }
       nuevoAlto = (int)Math.Round(img.Height * factor);
       nuevoAncho = (int)Math.Round(img.Width * factor);

       System.Drawing.Image miniatura = img.GetThumbnailImage(nuevoAncho, nuevoAlto, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);

       Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
       miniatura.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Comment: Siempre es bueno que puedas dar una minima explicación de como tu respuesta resuelve el problema.